# Return a private class implementing an interface keeping the implementation private

Tags: java

Static method `M` returns an object implementing interface `A`:

```
interface A { ... }
static A M() { ... }
```

Within `M` I would like to construct an object of type `B` and return that, given that `B` implements `A`:

```
class B implements A { ... }
```

I do not want client code to know anything about how `B` is implemented, I would *prefer* for `B` not to be a `static` class, `B` *must* be immutable and there could be different `B` handed to different clients. I want to prevent instantiation of `B` outside method `M` at all costs (short of reflection, as one user commented).

How can I achieve the above? Where and how should I implement `B`? Could you please provide a short code example?

My main problem is: how can I have "different `B`s?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A static inner class is probably your best bet. You won't be able to "prevent instantiation of `B` at all costs" since with reflection, client code can bypass all access modifiers.

Comment: Could I not implement a constructor and `throw` on its use to safeguard against reflection and then invocation? Is there a way for the class not to be static? Multiple clients should have different instances of `B` when calling `M`, different *immutable* instances. BTW, can you add code showing how you would implement your recommendation please?

Comment: If the only constructor throws an exception, how will the `M` method instantiate a new instance?

Comment: Question: will there be a fixed number of immutable instances of `B`? If so, an enum may be your best option.

Comment: The inner class `B` will have to be static if your `M` method must be static or else `M` will not be able to reference it.

Comment: No, there will not be a *fixed* number of immutable instances. But it's interesting to think about using `Enum`s.

Comment: The inner class does not need to be static.

Comment: @walrii The inner class must be static due to the constraints of the question. Specifically, the static factory method `M()` must be able to create instances.

Comment: @Kowser I rolled back your modification as it make this a substantially different answer. Please add that as a different answer.

Comment: @Asaph - Ah. Missed that. You are correct if M is the parent of the inner class.  But the static method in M might access or create an instance of another object (say a cache these objects) of class C and the inner class can be in class C.

Comment: Nitpick: you probably meant "static nested class". Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use anonymous inner class that won't be called B (is anonymous) but will implement `A` for example

```
interface A {
    void someMethod();
}

public class Test {
    static A M() {
        return new A() {// it will create and return object of anonymous 
                        // class that implements A
            @Override
            public void someMethod() {
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Without using reflection object of anonymous class can be created only by method `M`. Also it can't be extended so it is good first step to immutability.

Comment: Interesting. I had not thought about using an anonymous class. Really interesting. Is this the only way to accomplish what I need?

Comment: I don't think it is *only way* to accomplish that, but it is one of the easiest. This way there is no actual type that can be used outside of method `M` to create object of that class. Of course with reflection people can brake many restrictions and even create object of inner class (also anonymous), but without reflection this solution seems OK.

Comment: FYI, the name of the anonymous class will be `Test$1` (assuming this is the first anonymous class found within the Test class code)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `Proxy` implementation to hide the implementation class further

```
public interface A {
    public Object getValue();
}

public class Factory {
    public static A newInstance() {
        return new ProxyA(AImpl);
    }
}

public class ProxyA implements A {
    private A proxy;
    public ProxyA(A proxy) {
        this.proxy = proxy;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return proxy.getValue();
    }
}
```

All this is really doing is hiding the implementation of `A` under another layout and makes it difficult to create a instance of `ProxyA`

But as @Asaph points out, with reflection, it becomes next to near impossible to truly guard against people accessing various parts of the classes and objects...

You could also separate your interface and implementations via different `Classloaders`, so that you only ever expose the interface's to the developers and implementations are delivered by dynamic class loading them at runtime.  While not solving the underlying problem, it further complicates the matters for those trying to circumvent your factory.

IMHO